# onClickListener not working (properly) after ConfigurationChange in fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-configchanges

## Introduction

Huh, this is a **tough** one. At least, *I* think so...
To clear things up:

> *I did not find any answers to my question after searching the internet (using Google).*

Everything I found was about people setting up the `onClickListener`'s for their `View`'s wrong. I guess it is the same problem in my case, but none of the other problems matched mine.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665995/onclicklistener-in-fragments-does-not-work) seems to be the same problem... It has no answers.

## Setup

I've got three `Fragment`'s set up together with a `ViewPager` in my `AppCompatActivity`.

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_view_pager);
viewPager.setAdapter(new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

Handled by the `SectionsPagerAdapter`.

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return MainTextHolder.newInstance(tabIndicatorOnClick);
            case 1:
                return PostWriter.newInstance(tabIndicatorOnClick);
            case 2:
                return TopPage.newInstance(tabIndicatorOnClick);
            default:
                return Error.newInstance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    // ... more methods
}
```

In each of the `Fragment`'s I have some content plus a custom `TabIndicator`.

(the following `xml` file is my `View`'s for the indicator)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/fragment_divider_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="one" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/fragment_divider_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="two" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/fragment_divider_three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="three" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then I set an `OnClickListener` for each of those `View`'s (dividers) in the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup Bundle savedInstanceState)` method. The `OnClickListener` is already prepared in my `Activity` where I also instantiate my `ViewPager` so that I can change the current `Item` (`Fragment`/tab).

```
private final View.OnClickListener tabIndicatorOnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getTag().toString().equals("one"))
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true); // second argument for smooth transition
        else if (view.getTag().toString().equals("two"))
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
        else if (view.getTag().toString().equals("three"))
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, true);
    }
};
```

I pass that `OnClickListener` to the `Fragment`'s by putting it into my `newInstance(View.OnClickListener tabIndicatorOnClick)` method.

> *This is for one of the fragments. It is identical for the others!*

```
public static MainTextHolder newInstance(View.OnClickListener tabIndicatorOnClick) {
    MainTextHolder fragment = new MainTextHolder();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.putIndicatorTabIndicatorOnClick(tabIndicatorOnClick);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    return fragment;
}
```

My `putIndicatorTabIndicatorOnClick(View.OnClickListener tabIndicatorOnClick)` method is a `Void` in an `Interface`. It just applies the `OnClickListener` to the `Class`(`Fragment`).

```
@Override
public void putIndicatorTabIndicatorOnClick(View.OnClickListener tabIndicatorOnClick) {
    this.tabIndicatorOnClick = tabIndicatorOnClick;
}
```

## Does it work

Yes it *does*. It works perfectly fine... until a `ConfigurationChange` happens. In my case I tested it with *changing the orientation*.

## The Problem

What happens after that `ConfigurationChange` is that everything goes normally. The `OnClickListener` gets applied to **all** `View`'s in **all** `Fragment`'s, **but** the `tabIndicatorOnClick` `OnClickListener` is a *null object reference* in the second and third `Fragment`.

So in *PostWriter* and *TopPage* there isn't even really an `OnClickListener` on the `View`'s for what ever reason. But it gets better: In `MainTextHolder` `Fragment` the `tabIndicatorOnClick` is not a `null object reference`, but it does not change the `ViewPager`'s `Item` anymore. It runs the code, but it does not scroll the `Tab`.

When turning on *"Don't keep activities"* ind **Developer options** of the device and leaving the app, all `OnClickListener`'s are `null object references`. Even those in `MainTextHolder`.

## Summary

After the `ConfigurationChange` the `OnClickListener` gets passed into my first `Fragment`, but it is no working properly and in the *remaining `Fragment`'s* it is not even passed / a `null object reference`.

The issue *can be* replicated through destroying the `Activity` and then reloading it.

## In the end...

... I have no clue what is going wrong. I hope that I structured my question properly.

## May be of interest

> *minSdkVersion*: **14**
>
> *targetSdkVersion*: **25**

I already have a [SpringIndicator](https://github.com/chenupt/SpringIndicator) on my `ViewPager`. This does not feature an `OnClickListener` so I added my own *"overlayed"* indicators which have the needed `OnClick` feature. I also like the look of it, but if you can give me a better solution for my `TabIndicator`, I would also love to have that as an answer.

I came across the solution to put the method into the `xml` `:onClick` attribute multiple times, but for that I would need to create the same `OnClickListener` for every `Fragment` which is not really the nice way and it is also not *solving* my problem, but a way around it. - I would need to pass the `ViewPager` into my `Fragment` and then call that method from `xml` which is, as I said, just another way of doing it and not the way I prefer to do it. Also I don't know if it works. I'll most likely test it.

Other `OnClickListener`'s in the `Fragment` still work properly. So as I said the problem lays in the `OnClickListener` itself not working right/being a `null object reference`.

Comment: have you tried to change in your manifest android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" ?

Comment: this sounds like a Fragments lifecycle issue. Can you confirm if you can replicate the error by turning on Developer Options / Don't keep activities and then using the home button to go in and out of the activity?

Comment: @MilosLulic yes

Comment: @DavidRawson Yes I can replicate it. Doing it that way, the `tabIndicator` also is a `null object reference` in my first `Fragment` (MainTextHolder).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, well done for writing a detailed description of the problem. Many questioners on StackOverflow can learn from the ability of this question to articulate the problem.

This error would seem to come from not accounting for Fragment lifecycle changes. While inside a ViewPager, Fragments will pass through various states including hidden and shown when they are temporarily offscreen, and paused and resumed if they are offscreen and the system frees memory, and finally created and destroyed if the Android system decides to save the instance state of your Activity (such as from a configuration change). In the latter case,  Android will try and restore the state of your Fragments from saved instance state in your ViewPager. Since your Fragments have no way to save the `View.OnClickedListener` they were passed in the arguments, they end up with a `null` pointer when they are restored which is causing your error.

To fix the error, I suggest that you do not pass the `View.OnClickedListener` as a parameter to the Fragments. Rather, expose the `OnClickListener` to your Fragments via a public method in your Activity and have the Fragments get it themselves in their `onResume()`. This way you can guarantee that the Fragments will have a reference to the `View.OnClickedListener` whenever they are in a resumed state. So your `onResume()` might look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    OnClickListener onClickListener = ((MyActivity) getActivity).getOnClickListener();
    putIndicatorTabIndicatorOnClick(onClickListener);
```

}

Since you have set it in `onResume()`, you should remove it in `onPause()`:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    //set the onClickListener to null to free up the resource
}
```

Using `onResume()` and `onPause()` like this to free up resources from listeners is the approach recommended in the developer guide.

Of course, you will have to make sure your Activity also handles its own lifecycle by checking for saved state in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and restoring it appropriately.

Please note that saving instance state and restoring can be triggered in a number of ways:

1. Configuration state change (such as rotating the phone and causing the Activity to display in landscape rather than portrait
2. The device becoming low on memory (for example,  if a large number of Activities are in recent apps)
3. Turning on Developer Options / Don't keep activities and using home to put your application in recent apps and then navigating back to your app.

You will be able to use one of these methods to determine if you have correctly handled the lifecycles of your Activities and Fragments.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Much great information. Although I didn't get it to work. I figured out that in the lifecycle the `onCreateView()` method gets called before my `onResume()` method, so my tabIndicator is always null when being applied to the `View`. I know how to work around that, but is there any way better than setting the onClick in the `onResume()` method that you know?

Comment: setting it in `onResume()` is the recommended practice. You can check the Managing the Activity lifecycle and relevant sections of the Developers Guide. Fragments/Activities are not like POJO where you can always pass in dependencies as constructor parameters

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help. This had some really nice additional information.